# Minecraft Server Desyncing for no apparent reason?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

I recently started up my very own vanilla minecraft server, and got it working to the point where one of my friends could join. We played for a little while, until the server timed out. I alt-tabbed to the server window to see an error message along the lines of "Can't keep up! Is the server overloaded? Running x milliseconds behind". I don't have the best pc, so I'm thinking that maybe this is too intensive of a workload for it. So my friend and I turned down our view distance and kept on playing. After another half an hour of play, same thing happens, so I shut it down and lower the server-wide view distance in the config file. This time we are able to play up until the point when my friend has to go to bed, so we both log off. A little while later, I alt-tab to the server to shut it down, and I see that it's timed out with nobody logged on, and reported a synchronization of 20 minutes. It was able to stay up for an hour after changing the server-wide view distance. In my mind, this eliminates the option of it being too much of a workload, since how could there be any workload with no players connected? If it helps, I'm running the server off of a win10 pc, with a ryzen 3 2200g.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: There is still workload with zero players. But it should be a lot less. Which version do you play in? Also, what exactly is the error message you get?

Comment: I play in 1.13. The error message I got after leaving it with no one connected was: "[23:38:00] [Server thread/WARN]: Can't keep up! Is the server overloaded? Running 1322994ms or 26459 ticks behind". Also forgot to mention that I was running it in offline mode, could this have impacted it?

Comment: From my experience (running a small Minecraft server on a Surface 2 Pro) it depends a lot in the assigned memory. If the it is not enough, the server will spend quite a lot time managing it and will fall behind. However every now and then i also get this message you recieve (mostly when somebody joins the server or goes to the nether)

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that might be the issue because it said 300mb was 25% of the memory, how do I allocate more memory?

Comment: I start my server with a bat file that basically contains only "javaw -Xmx3G -Xms2G -jar  server.jar". -Xms defines the minimum size for memory pool and Xmx the maximum size. Just adjust the values for your needs